# Why is the /addTask route not working in my toDoList node app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried many methods but I'm always being hit with a different error, here's my code:

Here are my schemas where I referenced the user in my task and lists schemas, and referenced these 2 in the users schema.

Authentication is all working perfectly using Passport.js

```
// Tasks Schema
const tasksSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  user: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"User"}]
});

const Task = mongoose.model("Task", tasksSchema);

// Lists Schema
const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  items: [tasksSchema],
  user: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"User"}]
});

const List = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);

// Users Schema
const usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email:{
    type: String
  },
  password:{
    type: String,
    min: 6,
  },
  googleId: String,
  tasks: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Task"}],
  lists: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "List"}]
});

usersSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
usersSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = mongoose.model("User", usersSchema);
```

Here is my /addTask route, where first I'm trying to identify the user, then I'm creating a new task object from the Tasks model, and if the user was on his "Main" list, I'm trying to add the task there, but if it was a custom list I'm adding the task in the route of that custom list.

```
app.post("/addTask", async (req, res) => {

  if(!req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.redirect("/login");
  }

  const taskName = req.body.task;
  const listName = req.body.list;

  const user = req.user;

  try{
    const task = new Task({ 
      name: taskName,
      user: user._id
    });

    if(listName == "Main") {

      user.tasks.push(task);
      user.save();
      res.redirect("/main");

    } else {
      const foundList = await List.find({user: user._id, name: listName}).populate("List");
      foundList.items.push(task);
      foundList.save();
      res.redirect("/" + listName);
    }
  } catch (err){
    console.log(err); 
  }
});
```

It's giving mutliple errors such as:
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'tasks')
user.save() is not a function

Comment: On this line `const user = req.user;` what is `req.user;`? Can you `console.log(req.user)` to find out please? If this is not a mongoose `Document` or `Model` and it's just a plain JS object then there will be no mongoose methods to call on it.